# Unable to show SQLite option in Data Source in visual studio 2012 c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I am not able to show SQLite option while I'm going to add Entity framework via wizard in Visual Studio 2012 and Framework 4.5.

I have used below link:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

but still I'm not able to show it.

Comment: you want to show it when you are making a deployment?

Comment: yes , when i'm going to add Entity framework at that time unable to show the option of SQLite in data source.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add Sqlite from wizard,you just need to add the .dll to your File System Editor while making a deployment. Here is the full tutorial of how you can achieve this.
[include sqlite while build setup exe](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/699d9f78-3b67-4724-b50b-5ffb0422680a/how-can-i-include-a-sqlite-database-file-in-my-vs-c-project-while-build-setup-exe-?forum=winformssetup)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid , here i'm used sqlite with entity framework  and there is no option of sqlite.